# An alternative proof to: $P_{[X,Z]}=P_X+M_XZ(Z'M_XZ)^{-1}Z'M_X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, alternative-proof

With $P_A=A(A'A)^{-1}A'$ and $M_A=I-P_A$ denoting the usual orthogonal projection matrices, I'm trying to find an alternative proof to
$$
P_{[X,Z]}=P_X+M_XZ(Z'M_XZ)^{-1}Z'M_X.\tag{i}
$$
I already proved (i) by writing
$$
P_{[X,Z]}=(P_X+M_X)P_{[X,Z]}=P_XP_{[X,Z]}+M_XP_{[X,Z]}\\
=P_X+[0,Z]\begin{pmatrix}X'X&X'Z\\Z'X&Z'Z\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}X'\\Z'\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then I simplified the inversion above using the very last formula given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix_pseudoinverse). From that point on, some algebra simplifications produced (i).

This approach is a bit tedious and it relies on a block inversion formula that I will never be able to memorize. Does anyone know a more elegant approach please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the range of $[X,Z]$ is the same as the range of $[X,M_XZ]$ where from the second block we only removed the components which are already in the range of $X$ and in addition, we made these vectors orthogonal to the range of $X$. So (since $M_XX=0$)
$$
\begin{split}
P_{[X,Z]}&=P_{[X,M_XZ]}=[X,M_XZ]\left(\begin{bmatrix}X'\\Z'M_X\end{bmatrix}[X,M_XZ]\right)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}X'\\Z'M_X\end{bmatrix}
\\&=[X,M_XZ]\left(\begin{bmatrix}X'X&0\\0&Z'M_XZ\end{bmatrix}\right)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}X'\\Z'M_X\end{bmatrix}=P_X+M_XZ(Z'M_XZ)^{-1}Z'M_X.
\end{split}
$$
You won't completely avoid inverting a block matrix, which is, however, block diagonal now.